# instance variable and local variable

Tags: java

I'm very new in java. When we declare a local variable, it can be changed as needed in body of method. But when we declare a instance variable, we can't change it in body of class
    Sorry for my question. I know it's very easy but I can't fully understand.

```
class Test {       
    int x;  
    x=10 // error:cannot find class x  
    int a=10;       
    public void Method() {  
        int y;  
        y=1;  
        y=11;  
    } 
}
```

Comment: After `x=10`, add a semicolon right afterward.

Comment: Statements like `x=10` are not allowed outside methods unless they are part of a declaration like `int x=10`

Answer (score 1):

`x = 10;` is considered a statement and statements can not be use just anywhere within your class. They must be contained within a code block (between curly braces) such as in a **method** or a **Initializer Block**, or a **Constructor**:

```
class Test {       
    int x;
    int a=10;       
    {  
        // This is acceptable.
        x = 10;
    }

    // Constructor
    public Test() {
        // This is acceptable
        this.x = 10;        
    }

    // Overloaded Constructor
    public Test(int value) {
        // This is acceptable
        this.x = value;        
    }

    public void Method() {  
        int y;  
        y=1;  
        y=11; 
        // This is acceptable 
        x = 10;
    } 
}
```

[More Reading for you](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/object-initialization-in-java.html).